# $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2, ... , \alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ implies $\sqrt[3]{2} \notin F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2, ... , \alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ for $i=1,2,...,n.$ I want to show that $\sqrt[3]{2} \notin F$. I am trying to prove by contradiction assuming $\sqrt[3]{2} \in F$. However, I am not able to complete the proof. How should I obtain a contradiction from the assumption?

Comment: That's the main argument in the proof [doubling the cube is impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube) with ruler and compass.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:The degree of the field is $2^m$ and the degree of a field wich contains $2^{1\over 3}$ is divisble by $3$.

Comment: Right, and to my knowledge, this is the only way to prove this fact in the required generality.